# How to get components of m (message) for verifying

Tags: transaction-data, ring-signatures

I am trying to verify a transaction manually..but not knowing some components of message m.

The message is derived from:

```
m = H( H(tx_prefix), H(ss), H(range proofs) )
```

where

```
tx_prefix = {
    tx version (ringCT = 2),
    inputs {key offsets, key image},
    outputs {one-time addresses},
    extra {transaction public key, payment ID or encoded payment ID, misc.}
    }

ss = {
    signature type,
    transaction fee,
    pseudo output commitments for inputs,
    ecdhInfo (masks and amounts), output commitments
    }.
```

My questions are...

[1.] What is the format of **key offsets**?

Take a transaction as an example:

```
b43a7ac21e1b60ad748ec905d6e03cf3165e5d8c9e1c61c263d328118c42eaa6
```

The key offsets above is [799048, 782511, 1197717, 216704, 841722]. However they should not be the input format for hash. What the right format looks like?

[2.] What is the format of **transaction fee**?

The txnFee above is 26000000000 but the hex format is 8088e2ed60. Should I use 8088e2ed60 instead? And how it transforms from 26000000000?

[3.] What is the **range proofs**

In the example, Is the range proofs "rangeSigs"?

I am stuck here for a long time.. Please help on it, many thanks!

Comment: The key offsets and transaction fee are recorded as 'varints'. See [this previous question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/genesis-tx-varint). And yes rangeSigs should be the range proofs hashed.

Comment: What precisely do you want to verify? The MLSAG signature, the range proof???

Comment: Sorry for implicit information.. I want to verify MLSAG signature and I used a RCTTypefull case.

Comment: When verifying RCTTypefull type, what should I do if there is no pseudo output commitment for inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult to the [Varint description](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/2340) and transform from decimal to variant format for **key offsets** and **transaction fee**.

[1.] What is the format of **key offsets**?

799048 -> c8e230
782511 -> afe12f
1197717-> 958d49
216704 -> 809d0d
841722 -> faaf33

So the key offsets should be c8e230afe12f958d49809d0dfaaf33

[2.] What is the format of **transaction fee**?

Same as [1.] transaction fee should be 8088e2ed60

[3.] What is the **range proofs**?

I am not sure but I think the range proofs in MLSAG verifying is the concatenation of all **asig** and **Ci**. If it's wrong please correct me. Many thanks!

Comment: For RCTTypeFull, yes range sigs would be a concatenation of asig and Ci. You could check the implementation to see how it's done exactly get_pre_mlsag_hash().

Comment: ＠koe There is no pseudo output commitments for inputs in RCTTypeFull. So, I should pass it, right?

Comment: Well they don't exist, so yeah.